# xamarin binding objective c library

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin

I want to bind an objective c library (For using a cable) in xamarin. I am new to xamarin platform, Can anyone help me to convert the below .h file to "ApiDefinition.cs" in Xamarin binding project.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#ifndef CABLE_

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif
@protocol CableManagerDelegate;

/*

    This protocol), describes the main interface to the Cable Socket Manager layer.

    To use, call factory method below [CableManager sharedInstance]

 */
@protocol CableManagerProtocol <NSObject>
// set delegate for cable connect callbacks
-(void)setDelegate:(id < CableManagerDelegate >) delegate;

-(BOOL)isCableConnected;

-(NSString *)getAccessoryFirmwareVersion;

@end

@protocol CableManagerDelegate <NSObject>

//Cable was connected
- (void) cableConnected:(NSString *)protocol;

// Cable was disconnected and/or application moved to background
- (void) cableDisconnected;
@end


@interface CableManager : NSObject

+ (id < CableManagerProtocol >)sharedInstance;

@end
```

Comment: tried this?
[link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie/)

Comment: In corresponding xcode project the setdelegate function is calling by [CableManager sharedInstance] setDelegate =self];       In ApiDefinition.cs I have written the setDelegate function as 
Interface CableManager
{
[Static]
[Export (“SharedInstance”)]
CableManagerProtocol SharedInstance {get ;}
}

And I have created the dll using this. But I don’t know how to call the delegate function using the SharedInstance. Please anyone help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can't write it for you, but the sample below is the general pattern which you can learn more about in the guide linked below. One of your key challenges is going to be making sure the callback on the delegate fires. To Map this, check out the "Binding Protocols" section.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/

ApiDefinition.cs

```
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
  interface MyObjCWrapper
  {
    [Export("initWithArg1:arg2:arg3:")]
    void Constructor(string first, string second, string third);

    [Export("mySelectorTaking1arg:")] // note colon, takes 1 arg
    void DoSomethingWith1Arg(string filePath);

    [Export("getSomething")] // note no colon, takes 0 args
    int GetSomething();
}
```

> To complete this binding, you should add the native library to the
>   project. You can do this by adding the native library to your project,
>   either by dragging and dropping the native library from Finder onto
>   the project in the solution explorer, or by right-clicking the project
>   and choosing Add > Add Files to select the native library. Native
>   libraries by convention start with the word "lib" and end with the
>   extension ".a". When you do this, Xamarin Studio will add two files:
>   the .a file and an automatically populated C# file that contains
>   information about what the native library contains:

You will end up with a file like this (libLibraryName.linkwith.cs):

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: LinkWith ("libLibraryName.a", SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Objective-Sharpie](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie/). It will do the initial bulk of work for you and you just need to fill in the gaps...